# MongoDB index suggestion

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have the following query:

```
a : true AND (b : 1 OR b : 2) AND ( c: null OR (c > startDate AND c <endDate))
```

So basically i am thinking of a compound index of all the three fields, because i have no sorting at all. At the first step, with the index on the boolean field, i will eliminate the largest portion of documents.

Then with the index on the second field, i saw that OR clause creates two separate queries and then combines them, while removing duplicates. So this should be pretty fast and efficient.

The last condition is a simple range of dates, so i think that adding the field to the index will be a good option.

Any suggestion on my thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
a : true AND (b : 1 OR b : 2) AND ( c: null OR (c > startDate AND c <endDate))
```

could otherwise be translated as:

```
db.collection.find({
    a:true, 
    b:{$in:[1,2]}, 
    $or: [
        {c:null}, 
        {c: {$gt: startDate, $lt: endDate}}
    ]
})
```

Because of that `$or` you will most likely need two indexes, however, since the `$or` covers only `c` then you only need an index on `c`. So that our first index:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({c:1})
```

Now we cannot use the `$or` with a compound index because compound indexes work upon a prefix manner and `$or`s are evaluated as completely separate queries for each clause, as such it would be best to use `a,b` as the prefix to our index here.

This means you just need an index to cover the other part of your query:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({b:1,a:1})
```

We put `b` first due to the boolean value of `a`, our index should perform better with `b` first.

**Note:** I am unsure about an index on `a` at all due to its low cardinality.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. i just don't understand why we ignore indexes on fields that has boolean value - i am thinking of it as on my first query on this field, it will eliminate around half of the documents, just because of the few value possibilities?

Comment: @d1mitar That part is subjective to testing but basically it is down to the values, only two of them. Because of such low cardinality the index actually becomes quite useless because it is as bad as having to actually look at most documents at times, but this is down to testing and I would recommend you try with both an index and not an index and see which is better. If the selectivity is such that it will instantly remove about half of the documents from the result set then it could be better to have an index covering the boolean value

Comment: i understand now.. just last question - why the index no C field cannot be used in the compound index and it must be separate?

Comment: @d1mitar $or is evaluated separately in a query to the rest of it. It is like running a separate query for each clause as such this means that the index for c is used separately to all other indexes, since compound indexes work uopn a prefix manner, in this case b and b,a being the prefix to your compound (even if it had c on the end) index the $or would not pick up the index and use it effectively since it would be looking for a index with a prefix of c and only c